# Pod stuck in pending state due to pod affinity/anti-affinity

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

I have a problem, one of the replicas is stuck in a Pending state.

**Problem:** After another deployment one of the new replicas stacked and I have an empty node which satisfy all necessary requronmetns.

Deployment contains nodeSelector and affinity requirements:

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - vision-api-extract
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      nodeSelector:
        insttype: gpu
```

and there is 3 nodes with proper label

```
ip-10-0-11-16.ec2.internal                Ready    <none>   114d    v1.18.3    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b,insttype=gpu,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-11-16,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=us-east-1b,topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b
ip-10-0-11-206.ec2.internal               Ready    <none>   342d    v1.18.3    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b,insttype=gpu,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-11-206,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=us-east-1b,topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b
ip-10-0-11-44.ec2.internal                Ready    <none>   114d    v1.18.3    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b,insttype=gpu,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-11-44,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge,topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=us-east-1b,topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b
```

And here is a description of the pending pod

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/13 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 10 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

And empty node description as well

```
Name:               ip-10-0-11-44.ec2.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b
                    insttype=gpu
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-11-44
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g3.4xlarge
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=us-east-1b
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1b
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-00919faca1e45926f","efs.csi.aws.com":"i-00919faca1e45926f"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VtepMAC":"ce:02:a2:a2:5e:a7"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 10.0.11.44
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 26 Mar 2021 08:54:41 +0000
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-10-0-11-44.ec2.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Sun, 18 Jul 2021 11:52:59 +0000
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Sun, 18 Jul 2021 11:51:26 +0000   Sat, 17 Jul 2021 14:00:36 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Sun, 18 Jul 2021 11:51:26 +0000   Sat, 17 Jul 2021 14:00:36 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Sun, 18 Jul 2021 11:51:26 +0000   Sat, 17 Jul 2021 14:00:36 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Sun, 18 Jul 2021 11:51:26 +0000   Sat, 17 Jul 2021 14:00:38 +0000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.0.11.44
  Hostname:     ip-10-0-11-44.ec2.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-10-0-11-44.ec2.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         16
  ephemeral-storage:           60923672Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      125709124Ki
  pods:                        110
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         16
  ephemeral-storage:           56147256023
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      125606724Ki
  pods:                        110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 94c328b1fcaf4999b5de9f749ac998b8
  System UUID:                ec2c3806-d842-c53f-e93f-cf9059701bdd
  Boot ID:                    469aa16e-80f3-470b-9451-06078a78fa96
  Kernel Version:             5.4.0-1051-aws
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.9.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.3
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.3
PodCIDR:                      10.244.8.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.8.0/24
ProviderID:                   aws:///us-east-1b/i-00919faca1e45926f
Non-terminated Pods:          (8 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-5b64f64f64-x97ng     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         24d
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-2rwm4                      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         114d
  kube-system                 efs-csi-node-9dhb2                      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         114d
  kube-system                 kube-flannel-ds-amd64-9xkjg             100m (0%)     100m (0%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      114d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-nrjmh                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         114d
  kube-system                 traefik-9mpzr                           500m (3%)     1 (6%)      500Mi (0%)       800Mi (0%)     24d
  monitoring                  node-exporter-gj2qw                     112m (0%)     270m (1%)   200Mi (0%)       220Mi (0%)     114d
  monitoring                  prometheus-operator-6f98f66b89-dnjqd    100m (0%)     200m (1%)   100Mi (0%)       200Mi (0%)     24d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests    Limits
  --------                    --------    ------
  cpu                         812m (5%)   1570m (9%)
  memory                      850Mi (0%)  1270Mi (1%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0
```

Comment: What do you mean by empty node? There are pods running in the node you included

Comment: I mean only system daemonsets are running on this node. None of my services not scheduled on the node.

Comment: Does any of the pods currently running on this node, have a label `app: vision-api-extract`?